# Foreign characters in website

Tags: html, character-encoding

I found a website that contains the string "donâ€™t". The obvious intent was the word "don't". I looked at the source expecting to see some character references, but didn't (it just shows the literal string "donâ€™t". A Google search yielded nothing (expect lots of other sites that have the same problem!). Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Edit: Here's the meta tag that was used:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Would this not cause the page to be served up as Latin-1 in the HTTP header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your browser, switch the page encoding to "UTF-8".  You're seeing a [right single quote character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), which is encoded by the octets `0xE2 0x80 0x99` in UTF-8.  In your charset, windows-1252, those 3 octets render as "â€™".  The page should be explicitly specifying UTF-8 as its charset either in the HTTP headers or in an HTML `<meta>` tag, but it probably isn't.

Comment: In other words, there are 2 possible causes: 1) the output was pulled dynamically with UTF-8 characters, but the charset in the HTTP response header indicate that those characters should be viewed using CP-1252. 2) The source code file itself was filled with UTF-8 characters, but the file was saved as CP-1252 by the editor and served as such. Edit: as per your edit, the `<meta>` tag is not relevant, it's the `Content-Type` response header which counts.

Comment: The third option is that no charset is specified anywhere and the browser is incorrectly defaulting to the platform charset.  I'd bet on that one.

Comment: That would have been MSIE :) Which is not a real browser anyway.

Comment: Actually, this was happening in Minefield, not IE. But it turns out it wasn't a browser issue. The browser was set to Latin-1 encoding because the page's meta tag (which I didn't previous notice) specifies charset=iso-8859-1". Shame on the webmaster, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Character encondings in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) a lemme in wikipedia:

> HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) has
>   been in use since 1991, but HTML 4.0
>   (December 1997) was the first
>   standardized version where
>   international characters were given
>   reasonably complete treatment. When an
>   HTML document includes special
>   characters outside the range of
>   seven-bit ASCII two goals are worth
>   considering: the **information's
>   integrity**, and universal browser
>   display.

I suppose the site you checked, isn't impelemented with this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This has all got to do with encoding. Take a look back at the source, is there a tag at the top specifying it (charset)? My guess is it'll be UTF8 - although it could be something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread explains all](http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=31568).  A combination of using a weird UTF-8 apostrophe character (probably originating from a Word Document), on a server that probably reports its encoding as non-UTF-8, despite the page having UTF characters (and possible even correctly reporting its own encoding).

Comment: Web development 101: If you're going to use UTF-8 encoding, set the page encoding to UTF-8!